# How to take value from JSON response body and set it as an environment variable in Postman

Tags: json, postman

While hitting the service in Postman I am getting the multiple blocks in response body, i need to take one element value and need to store it in Environment variable to use it in next request.

Kindly help to take the value of `depositInfoId` and need to set in Environment variable.

I have tried with below one but not worked.

```
pm.environment.set("depositInfoId",pm.response.json().depositInfoList);
pm.environment.set("depositInfoId",pm.response.json().depositInfoList.depositInfoId);
```

Below is the sample Response body with few blocks:

```
{
    "qualStatus": "PASS",
    "blackList": {
        "blackListStatus": "PASS",
        "blackListStatusDesc": "CustomerName Match Not Found."
    },
    "fraudCheck": {
        "linesActivated": null,
        "status": "NA",
        "activationDetails": null,
        "errorDetails": null,
        "creditCheck": {
            "intlDialingEligibilityIndicator": true,
            "intlRoamingEligibilityIndicator": true,
            "creditCheckDetails": [{
                "linesApproved": 1,
                "approvedTerm": "24",
                "accountSpendingLimit": null,
                "lineDepositAmount": null,
                "securityDepositeAvailableIndicator": null,
                "creditLimitProgramIndicator": null,
                "noDeviceProgramIndicator": null,
                "creditOptionId": null
            }],
            "status": "APPROVED",
            "errorDetails": null,
            "accountNumber": "12345678",
            "creditAssessmentID": "123456",
            "contractTypes": null,
            "esimProductCode": null
        }
    },
    "depositInfoList": [{
        "depositInfoId": 863,
        "transactionID": "123456",
        "lineDepositAmount": null,
        "linesActivated": "1",
        "internationalDailingDeposit": null,
        "approvedTerm": "24",
        "depositSubscriberCount": null,
        "spendingLimit": null,
        "creditAssessmentId": "123456",
        "securityDepositAvailable": null,
        "creditLimitIndicator": null,
        "noDeviceProgramIndicator": null,
        "creditOptionId": null
    }]
}
```

In Environment variable values stored as below when I use first code.
`depositInfoId - [object Object] - [object Object]`

When I use second code fields are blank not stored in it.

Comment: I would request you to post valid sample JSON data to the question

Comment: Hi Div, here is full json response body.

Comment: Try `pm.response.json().depositInfoList[0].depositInfoId` this will return the id of the first record in the array

Comment: Thanks Div it worked. Why are we specifying like this depositInfoList[0]? due to multiple blocks?

Comment: Yes, `depositInfoList` is an array of objects, something like `array[object1,object ]`, if you want to access specific property of `object1`, you have to provide its index, hence, here `depositInfoList[0]` indicates the first record of the array.

Comment: Great Thanks..Got it..It was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pm.response.json().depositInfoList
```

This will save whole depositInfoList JSON data to the environment variable, and hence when you try to access it, it showed up Object Object.

```
pm.response.json().depositInfoList.depositInfoId
```

This doesn't make sense as `depositInfoList` is an array, you have to provide index when you want to fetch values from arrays.

```
pm.response.json().depositInfoList[0].depositInfoId
```

This should work, as you're trying to get the property value of the first record of the array `depositInfoList`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the whole object/array in your Environment/Global/Collection variables, you need to stringify the value first:

```
const jsonBody = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('depositInfoList', JSON.stringify(jsonBody.depositInfoList)); //will store the whole array as string
pm.environment.set('depositInfoItem', JSON.stringify(jsonBody.depositInfoList[0])); //will store first object from the array as string
pm.environment.set('depositInfoItemId', jsonBody.depositInfoList[0].depositInfoId); //will store if of first object from the array
```

Otherwise, you will store [object Object] value:

```
const jsonBody = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('depositInfoList', jsonBody.depositInfoList); //will store [object Object]
pm.environment.set('depositInfoItem', jsonBody.depositInfoList[0]); //will store [object Object]
pm.environment.set('depositInfoItemId', jsonBody.depositInfoList[0].depositInfoId); //will store if of first object from the array
```

Secondly, if you want to get value from the Environment/Global/Collection variable and work with it as array/object you need to parse it as JSON:

```
const depositInfoList = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('depositInfoList')); //returns array
const depositInfoItem = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('depositInfoItem')); //returns object
const depositInfoItemId = pm.environment.get('depositInfoItemId'); //returns number
```